# Magento1.9 to magento2.4 customer password migration

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, migration, password, magento2.4

I have **`Magento2.4`** but I need my **`Magento1.9`** customers password what should I do?

Comment: Do you have db of Magento1.9 ?

Comment: Yes I have. I have full database access

Comment: While doing migration, did you add hash key of magento1 into magento2 migration config.xml file? if added then all customer's passwords should be migrated properly and working fine in magento2 now. Please verify!

Comment: Where to get hash key of magento 1?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going down the route of importing M1 passwords, [Please try this solution, with changes below](https://www.aurigait.com/blog/how-to-use-magento-1-customer-password-in-magento-2/). This was originally written for 2.3x - in 2.4x the Encryptor model needs to be updated in line with the 2.4x changes. The original solution worked until we had to upgrade a site to 2.4.2, so we've had to make some changes.

Unfortunately, in typical Magento fashion, there's little to zero documentation about updating this functionality.

It's not perfect (I'm sure some PHP devs are facepalming right now), but it works. Customers with SHA1 passwords are able to log in again.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Encryption;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\Helper\Security;

class Encryptor extends \Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor
{
    const HASH_VERSION_LATEST = "1";

    protected $passwordHashMap = [
        self::PASSWORD_HASH => '',
        self::PASSWORD_SALT => '',
        self::PASSWORD_VERSION => self::HASH_VERSION_LATEST
    ];

    private $hashVersionMap = [
        self::HASH_VERSION_MD5 => 'md5',
        self::HASH_VERSION_SHA256 => 'sha256',
        self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13 => 'md5'
    ];
    private function getPasswordSalt()
    {
        return (string)$this->passwordHashMap[self::PASSWORD_SALT];
    }
    /**
     * Explode password hash
     *
     * @param string $hash
     * @return array
     * @throws \RuntimeException When given hash cannot be processed.
     */
    private function explodePasswordHash($hash)
    {
        $explodedPassword = explode(self::DELIMITER, $hash, 3);
        if (count($explodedPassword) !== 3) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Hash is not a password hash');
        }

        //Hashes that have been upgraded will have algorithm version history starting from the oldest one used.
        $explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_VERSION] = explode(
            self::DELIMITER,
            $explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_VERSION]
        );

        return $explodedPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Generate simple hash for given string.
     *
     * @param string $data
     * @param int $version
     * @return string
     */
    private function generateSimpleHash(string $data, int $version): string
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($version, $this->hashVersionMap)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unknown hashing algorithm');
        }

        return hash($this->hashVersionMap[$version], (string)$data);
    }
    /**
     * For migrated customers from magento 1 > 2.4
     *
     * @param string $data
     * @param int $version
     * @return string
     */
    public function addVersion($password, $hash){
        $hashs = explode(self::DELIMITER, $hash);
        if(count($hashs) == 2){
             return $hash . ":0";
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function isValidHash($password, $hash)
    {
        $agnosticArgonRegEx = '/^' .self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13_AGNOSTIC
            .'\_(?<seed>\d+)\_(?<ops>\d+)\_(?<mem>\d+)$/';
        try {
            if($this->addVersion($password, $hash)) {
                $hash = $this->addVersion($password, $hash);
            }
            [$hash, $hashSalt, $hashVersions] = $this->explodePasswordHash($hash);

            $recreated = $password;
            //Upgraded hashes would have been hashed with multiple algorithms.
            //Hashing the test string with every algorithm the original string has been hashed with.

            foreach ($hashVersions as $hashVersion) {
                if (is_string($hashVersion) && preg_match($agnosticArgonRegEx, $hashVersion, $argonParams)) {
                    $recreated = $this->getArgonHash(
                        $recreated,
                        (int)$argonParams['seed'],
                        (int)$argonParams['ops'],
                        (int)$argonParams['mem'],
                        $hashSalt
                    );
                } elseif ((int)$hashVersion === self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13) {
                    $recreated = $this->getArgonHash(
                        $recreated,
                        SODIUM_CRYPTO_SIGN_SEEDBYTES,
                        SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
                        SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
                        $hashSalt
                    );
                } else {
                    $recreated = $this->generateSimpleHash($hashSalt . $recreated, (int)$hashVersion);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            //Hash is not a password hash.
            $recreated = $this->hash($password);
        }

        return Security::compareStrings(
            $recreated,
            $hash
        );
    }
    /**
     * Generate Argon2ID13 hash.
     *
     * @param string $data
     * @param int $seedBytes
     * @param int $opsLimit
     * @param int $memLimit
     * @param string $salt
     * @return string
     * @throws \SodiumException
     */
    private function getArgonHash(
        string $data,
        int $seedBytes,
        int $opsLimit,
        int $memLimit,
        string $salt
    ): string {
        if (strlen($salt) < SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES) {
            $salt = str_pad($salt, SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES, $salt);
        } elseif (strlen($salt) > SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES) {
            $salt = substr($salt, 0, SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES);
        }

        return bin2hex(
            sodium_crypto_pwhash(
                $seedBytes,
                $data,
                $salt,
                $opsLimit,
                $memLimit,
                SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_ALG_ARGON2ID13
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Like I said, once I tweak this to better standards (namely when appending to the hash!) I'll update this.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

If your customer base is relatively small, you can consider sending email and remind them of your store upgrade so they can reset password.

Another option, our customer password migration plugin migrates your customer password without worrying about the M2 hashing algorithm for saving password. Therefore, your shoppers can possibly log into the new site normally without resetting password or creating a new account. For detailed information, kindly visit our profile.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can just add ":0" to the old md5 hashes from Magento 1.9

Next time an imported customer logs in, Magento 2 changes the hash to a new SHA1 one.

Answer (score -1):

Magento1.9 saved user passwords in md5, magento 2 abonndend md5 as it is insecure (read more [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure))

In M2 passwords are hashed via SHA-256 and a Salt Value.

To get the passwords from m1.9 to m2 you migrate your customers via the [official migration tool.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool-install.html) The passwords will still be md5 after migration but any customer action (login, change pw, reset pw) will transfer it to the new encryption.

You can also force the update for all passwords by running following command:

> bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: For me also, it is not working. Any other solution?