# Does exporting Customers and and re-importing them mess up passwords?

Tags: admin-panel, password

```
Magento 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto
```

I exported customers from Magento 1.9.3 and imported the file into Magento 2.4.5-p1. I can see the customers in:

- Customers - All Customers

But when I try to log in with my test account using my Email address and my previous logon password, the password does not work. It seems I've come across this somewhere before where the passwords don't get transferred properly because of how they are encoded?

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento1.9 to magento2.4 customer password migration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321125/magento1-9-to-magento2-4-customer-password-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exporting customers from Magento 1 and re-importing them to Magento 2 can cause issues with passwords. The reason is that Magento 1 and Magento 2 use different password hashing algorithms, which makes the password hashes incompatible between the two versions.

When customers try to log in to the Magento 2 store with their existing Magento 1 passwords, they will face authentication issues due to this incompatibility.

To resolve this problem, you have a couple of options:

Use the Magento 2 Data Migration Tool: This official tool is designed to help you migrate your data, including customer information and passwords, from Magento 1 to Magento 2. The Data Migration Tool takes care of the password hashing differences and ensures a smooth migration. For more information and instructions, refer to the Magento 2 Data Migration Guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/migration/migration-tool.html

Implement a custom password migration solution: If you prefer not to use the Data Migration Tool, you can develop a custom solution to handle the password migration. This may involve creating a module in Magento 2 that intercepts the authentication process, checks for Magento 1-style password hashes, and converts them to the new format used in Magento 2. This approach requires advanced knowledge of Magento development and should be done with caution to maintain the security of customer passwords.

Regardless of the method you choose, it's essential to thoroughly test the migration process to ensure that your customers can successfully log in and use your Magento 2 store.